# How to generate Cloudinary Authentication signatures in PHP(Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, cloudinary

I use Cloudinary with Laravel and I want to let users to choose from the existing files or upload new. How can I generate authentication signatures on the BackEnd(php in my case)? and pass it to the front end (JavaScript)?

I've tried to use unsigned upload preset to let users upload without requiring them to be signed in, but no luck.

```
mediaWidget = cloudinary.createMediaLibrary({
      cloud_name: "my-cloud-name",
      api_key: 'my-api-key',
      username: 'email id',
      uploadPreset: "unsigned-upload-preset",
      multiple: false,
    }, {
      insertHandler: function (data) {
        data.assets.forEach(asset => { console.log("Inserted asset:",
        JSON.stringify(asset, null, 2)) })
        }
      }
    );
```

I'm getting no error, but it always require user to login into cloudinary account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any SHA-256 hashing function/library to create the signature using the values (cloud name, timestamp, username) mentioned in the documentation. Using PHP as an example, the example in the [Media Library documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/media_library_widget#2_optional_generate_the_authentication_signature) looks like this:

```
<?php

$cloud_name = 'my_company';
$timestamp = '1518601863';
$username= 'jane@mycompany.com';
$api_secret = 'abcd';

$payload_to_sign = 'cloud_name='.$cloud_name.'&timestamp='.$timestamp.'&username='.$username;

$signature = hash('sha256', $payload_to_sign . $api_secret);
print($signature);
?>
```

This provides the same output as the documentation example: `5cbc5a2a695cbda4fae85de692d446af68b96c6c81db4eb9dd2f63af984fb247`

Then, in the Javascript code used to initiate the Media Library widget, you pass the same timestamp, and the signature from the server-side code, and it should open and log you in as the specified user:

```
window.ml = cloudinary.createMediaLibrary({
    cloud_name: 'my_company',
    api_key: '1234567890',
  username: 'jane@mycompany.com',
  timestamp: '1518601863',
  signature: '5cbc5a2a695cbda4fae85de692d446af68b96c6c81db4eb9dd2f63af984fb247' 
}, function(error, result) {
      console.log(error, result)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Cloudinary PHP SDK](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php) or there is a [Cloudder, a Laravel wrapper for Cloudinary](https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder) which has some nice helpers although it doesn't cover every use case.

The [Cloudinary documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload#directly_uploading_an_image) covers image and video upload using the PHP SDK.

Comment: thanks @BlueC for your response, I've already used the [Cloudder Package](https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder) you mentioned above for uploading files and it's works great. But what i need here is a way to use the [Media Library Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/media_library_widget) to let user choose from existing files or upload new and it's works perfectly when the user is logged in cloudinary account, and that's the problem, I want the user to be able to use the Media Library Widget without signing in.